# having difficulty searching for a date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, search

i am having problems searching through a list of dates, the results of the search are not appearing. the variable appointment date has been saved on the database as a datetime. this is the code i currently have in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime SearchDate)
{
    var query = from a in db.AppointmentProcedures
                where a.BookingStatus == false
                orderby a.AppointmentStartTime
                select a;

    if (SearchDate != null)
    {
        query = from a in db.AppointmentProcedures
                orderby a.AppointmentDate
                where a.AppointmentDate <= SearchDate
                select a;
    }

    return View(query);
}
```

this is the error I continue running in to:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.DateTime]', but this dictionary
requires a model item of type
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LaserculptFinal.Models.AppointmentProcedure]'
```

Comment: That doesn't look like FORTRAN to me.

Comment: Where is the error? In the view? Thrown in the controller? Does it work if you don't use `SearchDate`?

Comment: Have you tried using ToList() on your query?

Comment: yes i have tried the ToList and the line of code that is giving me build errors is:                                                  where a.AppointmentDate == Convert.ToString(SearchDate)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to pass to your `model` a `List` of smth but you are passing a query because you haven't enumerated it for example like this.

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime SearchDate)
{
    .....    

    return View(query.ToList());
}
```

It would help if you've showed us model which your view needs

Comment: i am using the index view of the appointmentprocedure model. i need the list on the index view to filter and only show the entries with the date that i am searching.

Comment: hw public class AppointmentProcedure
    {
        public int AppointmentProcedureId { get; set; }

        public int TreatmentId { get; set; }
        public int InventoryKitId { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime AppointmentStartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime AppointmentEndTime { get; set; }
      
    }
}

Comment: show please what is written in your view in line `@model....`, and have you tried `ToList()` on your `query`

Comment: not entity model(i assume you use it) but model class which you pass to MVC view

Comment: @model IEnumerable<LaserculptFinal.Models.AppointmentProcedure>

Comment: the appointment procedure is the model i am using. I am working on an MVC4 internet project

Comment: your mvc view is [strongly typed](http://www.howmvcworks.net/OnViews/BuildingAStronglyTypedView) and model you use for it is `IEnumerable<LaserculptFinal.Models.AppointmentProcedure>` i.e your model needs enumerable(e.g. `List`) of `AppointmentProcedure` so just enumerate you query and return it to the view(like `return View(query.ToList());`)